# How does serialization work for case classes and compared to java?

Tags: scala, serialization

When I have a case class that has methods on vals, what exactly will get serialized?

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String, age: Int) {
  val someNumber = age * 10

  def someMethod(a: Int) = ....

}
```

So from the above I would image the constructor parameters and the val someNumber would get serialized, while the methods would not.

So basically the state of the method gets serialized.

Are there any big differences between scala and java serialization?

Answer (score 9):

`case class` serialization in Scala is what we would expect from standard Java serialization.

case classes extend `scala.Serializable`, which in turn extend `Any with java.io.Serializable` (see [scala.Serializable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Serializable.scala)), so case classes are 'marked' serializable using the usual Java method of extending `java.io.Serializable`.

Note that we should speak of object serialization, not class serialization. What gets serialized is the state of the object instance  and it consists of the values of all members, declared or inherited. In the case of bodyless `case class`, like

```
case class User (id:Long, name:String)
```

all declared members will be serialized (eg. `id`, `name`).

If the case class declares inner member variables, those will be also included in the serialized form.

```
case class User (id:Long, name:String) {
  val foo = name.hashCode * id
}
```

the serializad form will include (`id`, `name`, `foo`).

We can mark members with the `@transient` annotation to avoid them being serialized.

```
case class User (id:Long, name:String) {
  val foo = name.hashCode * id
  @transient bar = "Private Bar."
}
```

the serializad form will include (`id`, `name`, `foo`).

Note that Java serialization always involve serializing the object graph consisting of all references attached to the object being serialized, so any object that's referenced by a member variable will also be serialized.

Like in this case:

```
case class User (id:Long, name:String)
case class Product (id:Long, name:String, price: Decimal)
case class Purchase (timestamp:Long, user:User, product:Product, name:String)
```

so, given:

```
val beerPurchase = Purchase(now, onlineUser, leffe)
```

Serializing `beerPurchase` will also involve the serialization of the `onlineUser` and `leffe` objects.

Note that every member of a serializable class must be also serializable or be marked `@transient`. Otherwise, attempting to serialize such class will result in a runtime `java.io.NotSerializableException`

***In a nutshell:  No surprises. case class serialization is what you would expect from standard java/jvm serialization.***

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an object and serialize it so you can easily see what's being serialized:

```scala
case class City(name: String, funActivity: String, latitude: Double)
val bengaluru = City("Bengaluru", "South Indian food", 12.97)
implicit val cityRW = upickle.default.macroRW[City]
upickle.default.write(bengaluru) // "{\"name\":\"Bengaluru\",\"funActivity\":\"South Indian food\",\"latitude\":12.97}"
```

The values encapsulated in the object are being serialized.

You can write your serializer to persist data in the object.  You can't serialize any JVM stuff/Scala stuff.  Serializing means converting the object to a string / binary.  Arrays of bytes have no way to store JVM stuff like methods.  See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/scala/serializing-deserializing-case-classes/) for more info about serializing Scala objects.